# Unity's Invoke or "StartCouroutine" won't work outside of Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object which isn't Monobehaviour but it has a reference to it. I tried to use Monobehaviours method Invoke(string methodName) to start a function (in the same class - that is not Monobehaviour) after a certain time, and I've got an error saying:

> Trying to Invoke method: StateManager.ActivateWaitStateAfterDelay couldn't be called.

Then I tried to use the StartCouroutine(string methodName) function to achieve the same task, but the problem is similar

> Coroutine 'ActivateWaitStateAfterDelay' couldn't be started!

Then I didn't pass the method name as a string but as an actual call to the function (it required to change the return type of the calling function to IEnumerator).

And this worked .. the method was called as expected.

Does anyone know why I couldn't call the function passing a string outside of Monobehaviour (of course inside Monobehaviour it behaves normally)?

P.S Function name represented as a string Is 100% correct.

Comment: why? because it's not designed to work that way - question unclear

Comment: Avoid using Invoke() at all cost, this is very error prone and quite slow

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) **works** with both, a `string` (method name) and `IEnumerator` .

But regardless of which of the two options (I would usually always prefer the `IEnumerator`) you use:

**Every Coroutine method needs to be of type `IEnumerator`!**

Checkout [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) where this is actually demonstrated with a `string`.

---

Different to [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) for which the method should be `void` and have no parameters.

In general note

> For better performance and maintability, use Coroutines instead.

---

Lets say you have e.g.

```
public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator ActivateWaitStateAfterDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

        Debug.Log("Hello there!", this);
    }
}
```

you can do both either

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public StateManager stateManager;

    public void DoIt()
    {
        stateManager.StartCoroutine(stateManager.ActivateWaitStateAfterDelay());
    }
}
```

or

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public StateManager stateManager;

    public void DoIt()
    {
        stateManager.StartCoroutine(nameof(StateManager.ActivateWaitStateAfterDelay));
    }
}
```